# instagram enc_password generation

Tags: c#, instagram, password-encryption

Im trying to make class for generating base64 string for instagram web auth via C#.
as base for my code i used this node.js sample - [click](https://github.com/FeezyHendrix/Insta-mass-account-creator/issues/140#issuecomment-601788881)
its looks great and work perfectly but i have no idea how realise this magic:

```
const key = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(32);
publicKey = '5a0b3cd9a12fef6c786afe28cfceef60550d27ea6657bb15be4a271eaadb0903';
const encryptedKey = tweetnacl.sealedbox.seal(key, Buffer.from(publicKey, 'hex'));
```

for aes-256-gcm encrypting i use BouncyCastle library but cant find similar action like `tweetnacl.sealedbox.seal` 
As I understand this action returned uint8array with encrypted publicKey

```
import nacl from 'tweetnacl';
import nonceGenerator from './nonce';
import {overheadLength} from './consts';
import {zero} from './utils';

export default function seal(m, pk){
    var c = new Uint8Array(overheadLength + m.length);

//overheadLength = nacl.box.publicKeyLength + nacl.box.overheadLength;

    var ek = nacl.box.keyPair();
    c.set(ek.publicKey);

    var nonce = nonceGenerator(ek.publicKey, pk);
    var boxed = nacl.box(m, nonce, pk, ek.secretKey);
    c.set(boxed, ek.publicKey.length);

    zero(ek.secretKey);

    return c;
};
```

it's very hard for me to do it myself, and I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: @RufusL - I think the OP is saying that he needs C#, but he's converting from node.js.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented it with some encryption packages and it works well for logining.

```
// Packages need to be installed: 
// Sodium.Core
// System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms

// The values of publicKey,keyId,version are from shared_data.
// You need to call https://www.instagram.com/data/shared_data/ to get shared_data first
public static string GenerateEncPassword(string password, string publicKey, string keyId, string version)
{
    var time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
    var keyBytes = publicKey.HexToBytes(); // Convert a hex string to a byte array
    var key = new byte[32];
    new Random().NextBytes(key);
    var iv = new byte[12];
    var tag = new byte[16];
    var plainText = password.ToBytes(); // ToBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
    var cipherText = new byte[plainText.Length];

    using (var cipher = new AesGcm(key))
    {
        cipher.Encrypt(nonce: iv,
            plaintext: plainText,
            ciphertext: cipherText,
            tag: tag,
            associatedData: time.ToString().ToBytes());
    }

    var encryptedKey = SealedPublicKeyBox.Create(key, keyBytes);
    var bytesOfLen = ((short)encryptedKey.Length).ToBytes(); // ToBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(short);
    var info = new byte[] { 1, byte.Parse(keyId) };
    var bytes = info.Concat(bytesOfLen).Concat(encryptedKey).Concat(tag).Concat(cipherText); // Concat means that concat two array

    // expected: #PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:10:1595671654:ARBQAFWLYGkTT9UU0dyUCkaGTRFu0PH5Ph5s86DUAbZ+B9xon8cKmnqQGaUo7bB4NHCMKQRY69b9LwaJZ1rDw1OFM0LEGtI+KbDuDC0QnfJM6o1no0XPOl73RJoUZ/OfN5nE2q/IdqX0NFinS0faRf8=
    var str = $"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:{version}:{time}:{bytes.ToBase64()}"; // ToBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String
    return str;
}

public static byte[] HexToBytes(this string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length / 2)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
}

public static T[] Concat<T>(this T[] x, T[] y)
{
    var z = new T[x.Length + y.Length];
    x.CopyTo(z, 0);
    y.CopyTo(z, x.Length);
    return z;
}

private static readonly DateTime _jan1St1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
public static long ToTimestamp(this DateTime d)
{
    return (long)(d.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1St1970).TotalSeconds;
}
```

I also put it on [github gist](https://gist.github.com/huoshan12345/44b1b4927b21d4ec21d1cbd61ea659da)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I just tried it and it causes `{"message": "There was an error with your request. Please try again.", "status": "fail"}`. Can you show requests? And it definitely works with the following trick: `string encryptedPassword = $"#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()}:{password}";` but it's temporary and not a good idea.

Comment: @nop I appended some code and comments just now. There are some lines that are fallible if you do some refactory. For example, the value of unix timestamp is used not only in the final result string, but also as `associatedData` in `AesGcm.Encrypt`. You can compare all my code and yours in detail. My requests are: 1.Http GET `https://www.instagram.com/data/shared_data/`to get shared_data. 2.Http POST `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/` to login with paras `username` and `enc_password`

Comment: I literally copy/pasted yours and still same error message. Here is my whole code: https://pastebin.com/mfSLWip3. It works fine with `#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()}:{password}` but it's kinda temporary, so you can't rely on it.

Comment: @nop I think the reason is your two requests do not use the same `CookieContainer`, you can try with a shared CookieContainer for all requests.

Comment: I just tried but the first request doesn't return cookies. The problem is in the encryption. I just tested a node JS example. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: I think the problem is in the key generation. It should be AES 256-bit. Somehow by executing it thousands of times, I got it to work once without changing anything in the code.

Comment: The first request return cookies when I try it. Here is the value: `Set-Cookie: ig_did=0737A3AE-B916-40EE-9480-975488C46FC0; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Fri, 26-Jul-2030 12:04:03 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=iMVUB6ckAnFJIRARtD8ebeo9hCmbPdQw; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Tue, 27-Jul-2021 12:04:03 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: rur=VLL; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: mid=XyAUMwAEAAH9PoB52SO_Pz5J_Bsw; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Fri, 26-Jul-2030 12:04:03 GMT; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/; Secure
`

Comment: Interesting. How did you get those cookies? https://i.imgur.com/JG2qfJz.png Can you send the exact code that you tested with? Even by manually logging on instagram, I'm not getting cookies in Fiddler. https://i.imgur.com/vTiiqY9.png

Comment: @nop I got some cookies from Fiddler. However it is not the point actually. The point is that when you send http data like `string postData = $"username={username}&enc_password={encryptedPassword}&queryParams={{}}&optIntoOneTap=false";` you have to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to encode the values. After I changed it to `string postData = $"username={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)}&enc_password={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryptedPassword)}";` from your code,  it works well now

Comment: Thank you so much, mate! That was the reason! The cookies are indeed not important. I removed them completely.

Comment: @nop My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried porting to c #, but there were problems with the decrypt

```
private static  encryptPassword(string password, string encryptionPubKey, string encryptionKeyId)
 {

            byte[] passwordAsByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptionPubKey);
            string decoededPubKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);


            decoededPubKey = decoededPubKey.Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    decoededPubKey = decoededPubKey.Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] randKey = new byte[32];
        random.NextBytes(randKey);
        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        random.NextBytes(iv);
    //String date = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    long tsLong = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() / 1000;
        string date = tsLong.ToString();

            var header = new MemoryStream(2);
        header.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(1)));
    header.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(int.Parse(encryptionKeyId))));
            MemoryStream timeAAD = new MemoryStream(10);
        timeAAD.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(date));
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(decoededPubKey, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
        Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] rsaEncrypted = rsaCipher.doFinal(randKey);

            MemoryStream sizeBuff = new MemoryStream(2);
        sizeBuff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    sizeBuff.putChar((char) rsaEncrypted.Length);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    AeadParameters parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(randKey), 128, iv, timeAAD.ToArray());
        GcmBlockCipher gcmEngine = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine());
        gcmEngine.Init(true, parameters);
    byte[] gcmText = new byte[gcmEngine.GetOutputSize(passwordAsByte.Length)];
        int len = gcmEngine.ProcessBytes(passwordAsByte, 0, passwordAsByte.Length, gcmText, 0);
        gcmEngine.DoFinal(gcmText, len);
    byte[] encPass = Arrays.CopyOfRange(gcmText, 0, gcmText.Length - 16);
        byte[] authTag = Arrays.CopyOfRange(gcmText, gcmText.Length - 16, gcmText.Length);

            var a = header.Position + iv.Length + sizeBuff.Position + rsaEncrypted.Length + authTag.Length + encPass.Length;
            MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream(a);
        result.Write(header.ToArray());
    result.Write(iv);
    result.Write(sizeBuff.ToArray());
    result.Write(rsaEncrypted);
    result.Write(authTag);
    result.Write(encPass);

    //return new Pair(Convert.ToInt64(date), Base64.encodeToString(result.array(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
 }
```

This is almost ready code, if there are corrections, write in the comments, I will fix it

Comment: seen that code at Github.but is for android auth.  web and andriod has different encryption

Comment: It seemed to me that the code was for pure Java, then it does not fit, sorry